# jQuery draggable tr transparent background

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5WFZ9/3/

Why when the tr is dragged the background color disappears? Could anyone please help me with this?

Am i'm missing something?

```
$( "#catalog tbody tr" ).draggable({
          appendTo: "body",
          revert:'invalid',
          helper: "clone"
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you start dragging the `tr`, jQuery clones it and places it below your `#catalog` (and outside of your table). Your CSS rules only apply inside the `table tbody`.

To solve it, you should setup a new CSS class, jQuery automatically adds `ui-draggable-dragging` to the created element, so use it!

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
   border:1px solid gray;
   background-color:red;
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WFZ9/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Its now .ui-sortable-helper. Thanks